# Android OS nav and status bars toggling in and out on fullscreen PWA

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

My PWA's with [`"display": "fullscreen"`](https://www.thepointless.com/apps/shooty-ship-pumpkin-smash/manifest.json) have recently started misbehaving. The Android navbar and status bar keep re-appearing during play. The apps still launch in `fullscreen` normally, but every touch event re-shows the OS bottom navigation and top status bars briefly (as you would normally see in `standalone` display).

I don't believe this is related any code changes on my end, as some of my old, untouched PWA's  have recently started behaving like this as well.

I'm on on a Pixel 5, Android 11, last updated within the last week.

Here is a [short clip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13zAlBp3bax5k1Zm87mJE5iI8cLkIJW6U/view?usp=sharing) showing the issue.

Comment: I experience the same issue in the native java android app in video player activity when i decided to use setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener. I thought the new code will work perfectly for android 11. but it didn't work out. The old fullscreenmethod() works perfectly with android 11. So I recommended downgrading the library or use the old method() that you have.

Comment: The old code for fullscreen in java
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            );

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was investigating the [same issue](https://github.com/arcomage/arcomage-hd/issues/40) of [ArcoMage HD](https://arcomage.github.io/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/arcomage/arcomage-hd)), an opensource React card game of mine.

The issue seems to be introduced by some very recent version (likely in Aug 2021 or shortly before it) of Android and Android Chrome (it'll be fine if you use the latest Chrome + an old Android).

This pretty annoying, bug-like behaviour makes `"display": "fullscreen"` totally unusable because when a user want to click a link/button, he will have to **double tap** the link/button! - the first tap cannot trigger the click of the link/button and can only make navigation bar and status bar appear, then the user must immediately tap the link/button for a second time, this time, the click or touch event is triggered.

Until Android/Chrome fixes this issue, a temporary fix that a PWA developer can do is: Use `"display": "standalone"`, then either put a "toggle fullscreen" button (using Fullscreen API) somewhere, or check `window.matchMedia("(display-mode: standalone)").matches` and if it's `true` (meaning it's PWA) then make a transparent button covering the whole page, when the user clicks anywhere on the page, he actually clicks the button, which requests the fullscreen mode and deletes itself.

(Previously I thought we can use `"display": "fullscreen"` then enter fullscreen mode with the API when the app is loaded. Unfortunately, Chrome [requires](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen) a user gesture to enter fullscreen)

For fullscreen toggling, you can use [this snippet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#toggling_full-screen_mode), or [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/) if you want better compatibility.

P.S. Chromium issue page:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1232956

**Good news: it's [fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1232956#c25) in Chrome 95.0.4637.0 which will be available on Canary (unstable version) in the next few days (and we'll probably need to wait a little longer for the stable version to fix it)**

**23 Oct edit: Chrome (for Android) stable version is 95.x now**

Comment: Thanks Tom. My eyes are dilated, so I'm having a hard time physically focusing on the linked bug/discussion. But, it looks like that's what I'm looking for (some confirmation that this is indeed just a Chrome bug). If that's the case, I'll see about getting that bounty back up and awarded once I can see/focus more clearly!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I believe might be your issue:

**Every time a tap is registered, the display flags are reset. You need to set the flags on each reset/tap, so it stays in full screen. When the tap occurs, it can be handled with a UI visibility event to reset flags.**

Thiese guides from google might help you:

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation#java

Comment: Questions for you: Where does it say each interaction resets the visibility? Does it apply to PWA's? When did it change? Why does it toggle back to fullscreen on it's own after a short period? What is the JavaScript equivalent of the Java in your links?

Answer (score 0):

most of the answers are Java and Kotlin, Javascript is a little tricky, you can adopt this to pretty much any of the JS flavors/supersets. I am using the standalone and hiding the controls of the browser

- [some info on the different display modes](https://superpwa.com/doc/web-app-manifest-display-modes/) more here on how to display below the controls [using safe mode css style](https://dev.to/oncode/display-your-pwa-website-fullscreen-4776).

> ##### I think the issue is that you have `fullscreen`, it will not work, you need standalone `"display": "standalone"`

1. First detect if the PWA is running in standalone mode inside our application like this:

```
// on iOS Safari
window.navigator.standalone

// on Android Chrome 
// this is key for you..
window.matchMedia(
  '(display-mode: standalone)'
).matches
```

---

2. Given various platforms, I recommend defining a `start_url` inside your `manifest.json`, it will save you in the long run :)
3. Then both to display in `fullscreen` & `remove native controls`, add the display property with the value `standalone` (fullscreen won't work). your `manifest` should have something like this:

```
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "Tykt.org App",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "/?standalone=true"
}
```

---

Ensure your `viewport-fit=cover` is *inside*:

```
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; viewport-fit=cover">
```

---

4. Add the mobile-web-app-capable and status-bar-style metatags:

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<!-- Bonus if you want some translucency, for e.g. try default, black or black-translucent -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"
    content="black-translucent">
```